# Prepending total (sum, count) of each column of pandas dataframe to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to prepend Sum/Count of specific column to the pandas dataframe before writing it to a csv file. I came up with a really delicate solution and wondering if anyone can suggest a better approach.

```
`df.to_csv(out_path, index=False)
 #reading content of csv file
 with open(out_path,'r') as my_file:
     content = my_file.read()
 #adding comma in the line below adjust cell in csv file and appending content of pandas dataframe after writing aggregate total/sum. 
 with open(out_path,'w') as my_file:
     my_file.write(',,,,'+str(df['E'].count()))
     my_file.write(','+ str(df['F'].astype(float).sum()))
     my_file.write(',,,,,,,,,,,,,,'+ str(df['T'].astype(float).sum()))
     my_file.write('\n')
     my_file.write(content)`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: Total has to be on the top of the file before header.

I am expecting following output:

[Sample Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EinJf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tips:** if you do not supply a path to `to_csv`, the function will return a string. You can use this string to manually build up your CSV content.

```
summary = df.agg({
    'E': 'count',
    'F': 'sum',
    'T': 'sum'
})
summary = summary.reindex(df.columns).to_frame().T

header = summary.to_csv(index=False, header=False)
body = df.to_csv(index=False)

with open(out_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(header)
    f.write(body)
```

Now you don't have to count the number of commas!

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a dataframe with the header information and write it to the csv together with the dataframe in append mode:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,4,6,2,3,9],[3,5,2,1,5,7],[4,6,8,9,0,4]], columns=list('ABCEFT'))

header = pd.Series(df.agg({'E': len, 'F': sum, 'T': sum}), index=df.columns).to_frame().T

with open(out_path, 'a') as f:
    header.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
    df.to_csv(f, index=False)
```